# Azure container job service connection

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-container-registry

I'm trying to run a container job in an azure pipeline using a container image from a private azure registry.

I followed [those instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/devops/pipelines/process/container-phases?view=vsts&tabs=yaml) and ended up with this pipeline configuration:

```
resources:
  containers:
  - container: build_container
    image: gxg08regtest.azurecr.io/ci-build-image:66162
    endpoint: SandboxGXG08

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-16.04'

container: build_container

steps:
- script: ./build.sh
```

It seems to follow the pattern but still give the this error:

> Expected 'dockerregistry' service connection type for image registry referenced by build_container, but got azurerm for service connection SandboxGXG08.

It seems to me like the parser couldn't match the correct pattern while parsing my image declaration.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is telling you the problem, as error messages (hopefully) usually do:

> Expected 'dockerregistry' service connection type for image registry referenced by build_container, but got azurerm for service connection SandboxGXG08.

You're using the wrong type of service connection. Add a Docker Registry service connection. The one you're using is an Azure Resource Manager service connection.

Comment: But this is the service connection I use to push the docker image, still it's not the correct type to use the image?